ArUco marker cannot be detected by OpenCV ArUco library in JAVA
I was working on a project where I have to detect ArUco markers in the images captured by the webcam. I was following the documentation until I found out that Java implementation of OpenCV ArUco module differs from what was described in the documentation, and deviated to finding my own way of detecting ArUco markers. Here is a minimal, reproducible example:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OpenCV.loadLocally();

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------
        // Adding the marker to detect in the dictionary.
        byte[][] marker =
                {{0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};

        Mat mat = new Mat(6, 6, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                mat.put(i, j, marker[i][j]);
        Mat compressed = Dictionary.getByteListFromBits(mat);

        Dictionary dict = new Dictionary(compressed, 6);
        ArucoDetector detector = new ArucoDetector(dict);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------
        // Initializing webcam (/dev/video0) and looping
        VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture("/dev/video0");

        while (cap.isOpened()) {
            Mat image = new Mat();

            cap.read(image);
            if (image.empty())
                continue;

            ArrayList<Mat> corners = new ArrayList<>();
            Mat ids = new Mat();

            try {
                detector.detectMarkers(image, corners, ids);
                if (!corners.isEmpty())                         // If the marker is detected,
                    System.out.println(corners.size());         // this should print something.
            } catch (CvException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

(OpenCV and ArUco detection library have been install by Gradle)
The above code was written to detect the marker at the center of the image.
Thanks for the help in advance, and I will provide more information appropriately if needed.

Edit:
As described in many documentations, blog posts, and stackoverflow questions, I tried getPredefinedDictionary method, but got the following error:
            ArucoDetector detector = new ArucoDetector(Aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(Aruco.DICT_6X6_250));
                                     ^
    constructor ArucoDetector.ArucoDetector(long) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; org.opencv.aruco.Dictionary cannot be converted to long)
    constructor ArucoDetector.ArucoDetector(org.opencv.objdetect.Dictionary) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; org.opencv.aruco.Dictionary cannot be converted to org.opencv.objdetect.Dictionary)

Here's the code in the original question with Dictionary changed.
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OpenCV.loadLocally();



        // ---------------------------------------------------------------
        // Adding the marker to detect in the dictionary.
        byte[][] marker =
                {{0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};

        Mat mat = new Mat(6, 6, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                mat.put(i, j, marker[i][j]);
        Mat compressed = Dictionary.getByteListFromBits(mat);

        // Dictionary dict = new Dictionary(compressed, 6);
        ArucoDetector detector = new ArucoDetector(Aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(Aruco.DICT_6X6_250));

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------
        // Initializing webcam (/dev/video0) and looping
        VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture("/dev/video0");

        while (cap.isOpened()) {
            Mat image = new Mat();

            cap.read(image);
            if (image.empty())
                continue;

            ArrayList<Mat> corners = new ArrayList<>();
            Mat ids = new Mat();

            try {
                detector.detectMarkers(image, corners, ids);
                if (!corners.isEmpty())                         // If the marker is detected,
                    System.out.println(corners.size());         // this should print something.
            } catch (CvException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

I also attempted to cast the return value of getPredefinedDictionary to org.opencv.objdetect.Dictionary, which is required by org.opencv.objdetect.ArucoDetector, but casting also have failed.

can you go into detail on "does not work" (title)? I agree that your dictionary construction looks outlandish. use predefined dictionaries. there's API for that.

@ChristophRackwitz as I mention in the comment of liaifat85's answer, I had troubles using predefined dictionaries, unfortunately. I'll add some details to the title right now.

in recent versions of opencv, the aruco stuff is scattered across one of the main modules and some pieces of a contrib module. -- if you get an unsatisfied link error, you should present the error. [mre]

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks for looking into my issue. Apparently, the Dictionary required by the ArucoDetector constructor is org.opencv.objdetect.Dictionary and the one you can get by getPredefinedDictionary method is org.opencv.aruco.Dictionary, which does not appear to be compatible.

@ChristophRackwitz If aruco stuff is scattered across the modules, would using a lower version of OpenCV resolve this problem?

the API changed as they moved code from the aruco module in contrib to the objdetect module. this should work: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/d67/group__objdetect__aruco.html#ga68e0379bcf3799b1ff7145769f8a09c8 where a Dictionary exists in the objdetect namespace for java: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/javadoc/org/opencv/objdetect/Dictionary.html and the getpredefined thingy also exists: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/javadoc/org/opencv/objdetect/Objdetect.html#getPredefinedDictionary(int)

if you solved this puzzle, feel free to post the answer yourself.

@ChristophRackwitz I used the same code as I attached to the question, since Java wrapper for OpenCV 4.10.0 does not containt getPredefinedDictionary, but somehow it detected the marker once. It's not detecting anything after then, however.

@ChristophRackwitz ...is what I thought. Actually, the method was in the wrapper, and my IDE just didn't show it. Now the detection works and I'll add it to the answer. Thanks for your help.

You can use Aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(Aruco.DICT_6X6_250). It is a more standard approach than creating a custom dictionary unless you have a specific need. The dictionary DICT_6X6_250 includes a wide range of markers. If you need a specific marker, you can customize the dictionary as per your needs. You can use 'DetectorParameters.create()' for more customizable detection. Here are some more OpenCV-related links that you may find helpful:
Aruco , Charuco detection with java and opencv
https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/How_to_use_AI_to_program_a_2DOF_ROBOT_Arduino_pyhton_opencv_chatgp_ps3eyecam_d3896679.html

Thanks for the advice, but apparently Aruco.getPredefinedDictionary leads to UnsatisfiedLinkError. I got the package from Maven repository, so am quite confused as to what is happening.

As @liaifat85 and @ChristophRackwitz mentioned, using getPredefinedDictionary was the solution. I just wasn't able to find it. Also, using the old version (in my case, it was 4.0.1) was the problem. Credits to both of them. I wouldn't have been able to solve this problem without them.
